# How to send a post request using CURL in nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, selenium, curl, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I have a use case requirement where i have to send a post request using a curl command before running ANY test in Nightwatch. Example: "curl -X POST [https://example.com/"](https://example.com/%22).

I am aware that there is something called globals in nightwatch where a "before" hook can be used but not sure about how to execute above curl command in that before hook. The manual way of doing it to invoke the terminal first and enter the command and then run the test.
Can anybody please help and explain how to achieve this.